# ssh local tunnel to VM

Tags: ssh, kvm, ssh-tunneling

So, can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Everything from remote host (`192.168.1.3`):

```
ssh -L 9000:192.168.1.2:80 login@192.168.1.2
elinks http:127.0.0.1:9000
```

and I can see a web page.

other host with www (`192.168.1.1`):

```
ssh -L 9000:192.168.1.3:80 login@192.168.1.2
elinks 127.0.0.1:9000
```

and I see another web page.

BUT when I try to access a Virtual Machine on `192.168.1.2`, then nothing:

```
ssh -L 9000:172.31.255.29:80 login@192.168.1.2
```

I was trying to log rejected packages (nothing found), `tcpdump` shows answer from vm to `virbr0`

What could be the problem? I have got only one clue, that it might be unix socket related but need advice from somebody who understands that better than me.

Comment: Why does the VM seem to have an external IP? Can you access the VM at `172.31.255.29` from `192.168.1.2`?

Comment: yes of course I can access VM from server. It's not trivial problem. Except for that: I can access www - port 9000 (ssh -L 9000:192.168.1.2.80 login@192.168.1.2) and also directly (port 80). After that I add rule to table nat, chain PREROUTING for DNAT 192.168.1.2:80 to 172.31.255.28:80 and everything working fine. The problem is related to ssh tunnel. I suppose data flow is quite diferent there and that is the reason I'm asking for help because it does not work properly.

Comment: and by the way packets going out to virtual machine:  kernel: [11043.707646] BROKEN IN= OUT=virbr1 SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=172.31.255.27 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=47205 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=43258 DPT=80 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0. Seems as if they lost state etablished/related

Comment: Are you sure something is running on `172.31.255.29:80` and `172.31.255.29` is resolvable from outside?

Comment: on 172.31.255.29:80 (VM) there is httpd. 172.31.255.29 isn't reslvable from outside. That is the reason I want connect through ssh tunnel from outsider host: 'ssh -L 9000:172.31.255.29:80 login@192.168.1.2'